# MySQL beginner query ignorance. Changing the table id value so it places everything once again in numerical order

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
    id  name            age
    2   Sandy Smith     21
    4   Alie Smith      19
    5   James Smith     11
```

Hello, I am new to programming and am watching tutorials online this summer in my free time. I know this is a simple question but I've searched online and I can't find exactly what I need.

I deleted a row so now i no longer have "id 2 3 4 5". I'm left with 2, 4 ,5". I don't know the MySQL query to place alie smith as #3 and james smith as #4. Please help me out with this query. Thanks

Comment: IDs don't need to be consecutive, only unique.  They're not supposed to be human-friendly but mainly machine-friendly.  Trying to re-number them for human-friendly purposes will cause more problems than it solves.  Specifically, any table which references records in the re-numbered table would now reference the wrong records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have the original insert statements or can re-create them, you can do a `TRUNCATE TABLE [tablenamehere]` then reinsert the data. Could be handy if you're trying to get the table back to a known state.

Comment: hmm, ok that sounds interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to.  The point of a primary key is that is UNIQUE.  ID field will auto increment on its own. The only way to do this would be to take the primary key attribute off of the ID column so that you can control it manually, insert the correct id's, and then put the key on.  Read up on normalizing databases and it will make more sense.

Comment: Agree with mscard02 - but I'll also add that you can make sure that things stay in order by adding the ORDER BY clause to the end of your select query like this:  SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id ASC